# Do If else have priority in verilog?

Tags: verilog

I have some query about the priority of if else in verilog.
For example.

```
  If (a)
  b
  else if c
  d
  else if e
  f
  else 
  g
```

At here, those a,b,c...g are all searched ?
How do those have priorities in if~else in verilog?

Comment: What do you mean by 'searched'? There's no precedence, or at least it depends on what b,d,f,g are.

Comment: @Vladmir Cravero  How does it synthesis?

Comment: They're all synthesised, provided a/c/e aren't compile-time constants.

Comment: @ pjc50  I meant as gate.

Comment: Well. I beg to differ. AFAIK (and pls correct me if I'm wrong), if else construct infers a 'Priority routing Network', with the outermost if carrying highest priority. All of it is synthesized using a ladder of multiplexers (2:1 Mux I believe).

Comment: Does anyone know how to synthsis as gate logic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An if-else construct infers a priority routing network. Following example is taken directly from a verilog book :

```
if
 (m==n)
r = a + b + c ;
else if (m > n )
r = a - b ;
else
r = c + 1 ;
```

The circuit is as shown :

[image]

As you can see, the outermost if is given a priority in the sense that it is routed first if a match is found, bypassing others.

Ref : [Fpga prototyping by verilog](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470185325)

Comment: Thanks . There are priorities in there as cuicuit. First m and n equality check then m and n size check.

Comment: Yes. And finally a default case when none of the above exists.

Comment: Mind giving a reference to the book?

Comment: Added the link to the book.

Comment: Should the synthesis tool recognize the three cases as mutually exclusive and be able to do one parallell mux?